# AlpineJS - preventDefault on the triggered event

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm really new on web dev and started working on a project using TailwindCSS and AlpineJS.
The problem is that, whenever the page gets loaded, the events (@click, @mouseenter and @mouseleave) are triggered.
I've already tried adding .prevent to the events (@click.prevent, @mouseenter.prevent and @mouseleave.prevent) but it didn't work.
I can't show all the code because it's too big, so here's part of it:

Where @mouseenter and @mouseleave is:

```
<!-- Finances -->
<div 
  class="hidden md:flex sm:ml-6"
  id="nav-heading"
  aria-labelledby="nav-heading"
  x-data="{ financesOpen: false }"
  :aria-expanded="financesOpen"
>
  <button 
    type="button" 
    class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-base font-bold leading-3 text-gray-900 transition duration-150 ease-in-out border-b-2 hover:border-indigo-500 focus:no-underline lg:text-lg hover:no-underline hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 focus:text-gray-900"
    :aria-expanded="financesOpen"
    aria-controls="nav-list"
    @mouseenter="financesOpen = !financesOpen"
    @mouseleave="financesOpen = !financesOpen"
    @click.away="financesOpen = false"
  >
    Finanças
  </button>

  <div 
    x-show.transition.in.duration.100ms.origin.top.left.opacity.scale.10.out.duration.100ms.origin.bottom.right.opacity.scale.10="financesOpen" 
    id="nav-list" 
    class="absolute z-10 w-auto origin-top-left rounded-md shadow-lg top-16"
  >
  <!--
    Finances dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.
  -->
    <div class="py-1 bg-white rounded-md shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Exchange Earn</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Ganhe criptomoedas enquanto dorme</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Exchange Pool</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Minere mais recompensas conectando-se com o nosso grupo</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
              <p class="font-medium">Exchange Visa Card</p>
              <svg class="h-4 ml-1" width="20px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 20 16" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                  <title>fiber_new</title>
                  <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                  <g id="Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Rounded" transform="translate(-714.000000, -910.000000)"><g id="AV" transform="translate(100.000000, 852.000000)"><g id="-Round-/-AV-/-fiber_new" transform="translate(612.000000, 54.000000)"><g>
                          <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-17" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"></rect>
                          <path d="M20,4 L4,4 C2.89,4 2.01,4.89 2.01,6 L2,18 C2,19.11 2.89,20 4,20 L20,20 C21.11,20 22,19.11 22,18 L22,6 C22,4.89 21.11,4 20,4 Z M8.5,14.21 C8.5,14.64 8.14,15 7.71,15 C7.46,15 7.22,14.88 7.07,14.67 L4.75,11.5 L4.75,14.38 C4.75,14.73 4.47,15 4.13,15 C3.79,15 3.5,14.72 3.5,14.38 L3.5,9.79 C3.5,9.36 3.86,9 4.29,9 L4.34,9 C4.6,9 4.84,9.12 4.99,9.33 L7.25,12.5 L7.25,9.62 C7.25,9.28 7.53,9 7.88,9 C8.23,9 8.5,9.28 8.5,9.62 L8.5,14.21 Z M13.5,9.64 C13.5,9.99 13.22,10.26 12.88,10.26 L11,10.26 L11,11.38 L12.88,11.38 C13.23,11.38 13.5,11.66 13.5,12 L13.5,12.01 C13.5,12.36 13.22,12.63 12.88,12.63 L11,12.63 L11,13.74 L12.88,13.74 C13.23,13.74 13.5,14.02 13.5,14.36 C13.5,14.71 13.22,14.98 12.88,14.98 L10.35,14.98 C9.88,14.98 9.5,14.6 9.5,14.13 L9.5,9.83 C9.5,9.38 9.88,9 10.35,9 L12.88,9 C13.23,9 13.5,9.28 13.5,9.62 L13.5,9.64 Z M20.5,14 C20.5,14.55 20.05,15 19.5,15 L15.5,15 C14.95,15 14.5,14.55 14.5,14 L14.5,9.62 C14.5,9.28 14.78,9 15.12,9 C15.46,9 15.74,9.28 15.74,9.62 L15.74,13.51 L16.87,13.51 L16.87,10.61 C16.87,10.26 17.15,9.99 17.49,9.99 C17.83,9.99 18.11,10.27 18.11,10.61 L18.11,13.5 L19.23,13.5 L19.23,9.62 C19.23,9.27 19.51,9 19.85,9 C20.19,9 20.47,9.28 20.47,9.62 L20.47,14 L20.5,14 Z" id="Icon-Color" fill="#1D1D1D"></path>
                  </g></g></g></g></g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Converta e faça pagamentos usando suas criptomoedas no mundo todo</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
            <p class="font-medium">Empréstimos de criptomoedas</p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Obtenha um empréstimo instantâneo garantido por ativos de criptomoeda</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 hover:no-underline focus:no-underline focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">
        <div class="flex flex-row">
          <img class="w-4 h-4 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/80/000000/rhombus.png"/>
          <div class="flex flex-col">
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
              <p class="font-medium">Liquid Swap</p>
              <svg class="h-4 ml-1" width="20px" height="16px" viewBox="0 0 20 16" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                  <title>fiber_new</title>
                  <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                  <g id="Icons" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><g id="Rounded" transform="translate(-714.000000, -910.000000)"><g id="AV" transform="translate(100.000000, 852.000000)"><g id="-Round-/-AV-/-fiber_new" transform="translate(612.000000, 54.000000)"><g>
                          <rect id="Rectangle-Copy-17" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24"></rect>
                          <path d="M20,4 L4,4 C2.89,4 2.01,4.89 2.01,6 L2,18 C2,19.11 2.89,20 4,20 L20,20 C21.11,20 22,19.11 22,18 L22,6 C22,4.89 21.11,4 20,4 Z M8.5,14.21 C8.5,14.64 8.14,15 7.71,15 C7.46,15 7.22,14.88 7.07,14.67 L4.75,11.5 L4.75,14.38 C4.75,14.73 4.47,15 4.13,15 C3.79,15 3.5,14.72 3.5,14.38 L3.5,9.79 C3.5,9.36 3.86,9 4.29,9 L4.34,9 C4.6,9 4.84,9.12 4.99,9.33 L7.25,12.5 L7.25,9.62 C7.25,9.28 7.53,9 7.88,9 C8.23,9 8.5,9.28 8.5,9.62 L8.5,14.21 Z M13.5,9.64 C13.5,9.99 13.22,10.26 12.88,10.26 L11,10.26 L11,11.38 L12.88,11.38 C13.23,11.38 13.5,11.66 13.5,12 L13.5,12.01 C13.5,12.36 13.22,12.63 12.88,12.63 L11,12.63 L11,13.74 L12.88,13.74 C13.23,13.74 13.5,14.02 13.5,14.36 C13.5,14.71 13.22,14.98 12.88,14.98 L10.35,14.98 C9.88,14.98 9.5,14.6 9.5,14.13 L9.5,9.83 C9.5,9.38 9.88,9 10.35,9 L12.88,9 C13.23,9 13.5,9.28 13.5,9.62 L13.5,9.64 Z M20.5,14 C20.5,14.55 20.05,15 19.5,15 L15.5,15 C14.95,15 14.5,14.55 14.5,14 L14.5,9.62 C14.5,9.28 14.78,9 15.12,9 C15.46,9 15.74,9.28 15.74,9.62 L15.74,13.51 L16.87,13.51 L16.87,10.61 C16.87,10.26 17.15,9.99 17.49,9.99 C17.83,9.99 18.11,10.27 18.11,10.61 L18.11,13.5 L19.23,13.5 L19.23,9.62 C19.23,9.27 19.51,9 19.85,9 C20.19,9 20.47,9.28 20.47,9.62 L20.47,14 L20.5,14 Z" id="Icon-Color" fill="#1D1D1D"></path>
                  </g></g></g></g></g>
              </svg>
            </div>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">Faça trading e ganhe comissões com pools de liquidez</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where @click is:

```
<!-- Security -->
<div
  id="nav-heading"
  class="relative hidden mr-4 lg:block"
  aria-labelledby="nav-heading"
  x-data="{ securityOpen: false }"
  :aria-expanded="securityOpen"
>
  <button 
    class="flex-shrink-0 block group focus:outline-none"
    :aria-expanded="securityOpen"
    aria-controls="nav-list"
    @click="securityOpen = !securityOpen"
    @click.away="securityOpen = false"
  >
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-10 h-10 pb-2 rounded-full sm:bg-red-500 sm:pb-0 animate-pulse">
      <img class="w-8 h-8" src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/64/000000/shield.png"/>
    </div>
  </button>
  <!--
    Security dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.
  -->
  <div 
    x-show.transition.in.duration.100ms.origin.top.right.opacity.scale.10.out.duration.100ms.origin.bottom.left.opacity.scale.10="securityOpen" 
    id="nav-list" 
    class="absolute transform translate-x-20 sm:transform-none right-0 mt-1.5 text-white origin-top-right bg-indigo-900 border rounded-md shadow-lg w-80"
  >
    <div class="p-4 border-b" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
      <h4>NÍVEL DE SEGURANÇA ATUAL</h4>
      <h4 class="text-red-600">CRITICAMENTE BAIXO</h4>
      <p>Sua conta tem um número criticamente baixo de recursos de segurança ativados. É altamente recomendável que você ative esses recursos para proteger sua conta.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inline-flex items-center p-4" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
      <img class="w-8 h-8 mr-1" src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/64/000000/shield.png"/>
      <a class="text-lg font-medium text-white cursor-pointer lg:text-xl hover:text-gray-300 focus:no-underline hover:no-underline">Proteja sua conta</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of showing us all of your code, can you show us the area you think the issue is in, and show us the file where `@mouseenter`, `@mouseleave`, `@click`, etc, is?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added more of the code showing where the triggered events are.

Comment: Are you sure the events are being triggered? It sounds to me like what you want is to hide the contents of the Alpine.js code until Alpine is available, which you can do with `x-cloak`, see the docs https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/#x-cloak

Comment: Yes. When the page is getting rendered, all the AlpineJS events are triggered, which means that when someone visits the page, for example, all the dropdowns are opened and closed because the @click event gets triggered.

Comment: I've dived deeper into Alpine's x-cloak that's actually it! So far, I added:
<style>
  [x-cloak] {
      display: none !important;
      visibility: hidden;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
</style>

and x-cloak inside of the wrapping divs, like:
<div 
          class="hidden ml-6 lg:ml-0 2xl:ml-4 lg:flex"
          id="nav-heading"
          aria-labelledby="nav-heading"
          x-data="{ ordersOpen: false }"
          :aria-expanded="ordersOpen"
          x-cloak
        >
But what happened is that the initialized components flashes faster. Am I missing something? @Hugo

Comment: Are you putting the CSS rules directly in the HTML?

Comment: I was doing that @Hugo, but later I found out I had to include the <style> [x-cloak] { display: none !important; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; } </style> on app.css file to set it as a global style.
Now I'm strugglin to use x-cloak the right way on my project. I was putting x-cloak at the top parent div on the Security dropdown panel, but it's not really working, because it still flashes the div on the screen, but just faster than it would without x-cloak.

Comment: You should use `<style>[x-cloak] { display: none }</style>` outside of the app.css file to avoid the flash. Alternatively you can add `style="display: none"` to the elements which should be hidden (and use `x-show` to display them once Alpine.js has loaded)

Comment: Finally I made it, @Hugo. Thank you very much, you really helped me on my work!